# Angular 4 - how do I get access to nested components inside a template?

Tags: angular

I have a hierarchy of components:

```ts
App
|
Child
|
Input
```

The component "Child" accepts a template from it's parent like this:

```ts
<my-child>
    <ng-template>
        <my-input></my-input>
        <span>asdasdas</span>
        <my-input></my-input>
        <my-input></my-input>
    </ng-template>    
</my-child>
```

As you can see in the template there's a number of input components. Now **I would like to get an access to the list of `<my-input>` components from the child component.** What I tried now was to use the @ContentChildren/@ViewChildren, but it doesn't seem to work. The code of Child component:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputTemplate" #input></ng-template>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})

export class Child implements OnInit, OnAfterViewInit {

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) inputTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ViewChildren(InputComponent) inputComponents : QueryList<InputComponent>;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    //THIS SHOULD NOT BE EMPTY
    console.log(this.inputComponents.toArray());
  }
}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how/if it is possible to get a list of InputComponents from the Child component.

Maybe I shouldn't be using a template here at all? Is there any other way to make this control customisable and still be able to access a list of nested InputComponents?

In case you want to play with it [here's the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lm0KSpjO2kwjKxlrdmfO?p=preview)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `@ContentChildren(InputComponent)` instead of `@ViewChildren()` and subscribing to changes

```ts
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    //THIS SHOULD NOT BE EMPTY
    this.inputComponents.changes.subscribe(c => console.log(this.inputComponents.toArray()));
    //console.log(this.inputComponents.toArray());
  }
```

worked for me, but honestly I don't know myself why `@ContentChildren()` instead of `@ViewChildren()` is working.

[**Plunker link**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UoAzpH6MKClghgCsPRjV?p=preview)

Comment: `ViewChildren` doesn't work because <my-input> components inside content DOM (not in the view DOM)

Comment: TemplateRef is also bound using ContentChild and it works. I didn't know about the ability to subscribe to changes. As far as I've read it should have been bound in ngAfterViewInit, but since those components are nested inside a template I suppose that it actually happened later. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Yeah, but `TemplateRef` actually is passed content, but the template is then rendered inside the component and I had expected the created components to become children. Yes, that's the reason. Only the `TemplateRef` is available in `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`, `ngTemplateOutlet` only renders after this change detection cycle is completed.

Comment: @taras-d it's only a template that is passed to the child, at this time no components are being instantiated, `ngTemplateOutlet` stamps the template. I guess the content of the template is also just transcluded to the `<template>` element though, which would actually make them part of the parent component. Seen from this angle, I guess you are right.